# How can i open my application in Internet Explorer 11.0 in selenium web driver?

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

How can i open my application in Internet Explorer 11.0 in selenium web driver?

I am using this code:

```
**DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        caps.setCapability(
            InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,
            true);
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","E:\\Vishal Bhatt\\eclipse\\IEDriverServer\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        //WebDriver driver= new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");**
```

But it is not working.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting an error.Internet explorer browser open as blank .doesn't open google page. and is it necessary to write DesiredCapabilities class for IE.

Answer (score 0):

please try this updated code

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        caps.setCapability(
            InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,
            true);

        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","E:\\Vishal Bhatt\\eclipse\\IEDriverServer\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
        driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, IE 11 is not yet supported by `InternetExplorerDriver`. Microsoft made a change in IE11 that broke the IE driver's ability to stay connected with the browser. This is true even if you have set Protected Mode settings properly. Until and unless we receive a workaround from Microsoft for the issue, this will continue to be the case.